# create new data frame by reshaping existing data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I'm a python beginner. Greatly appreciated if someone could help me with below problem. what I have:

```
>>>df = pd.DataFrame({'2-day-sale' : [4], '3-day sale' : [7],'2-day-volume' : [10],'3-day-volume' : [100]});
>>>output:
      2-day-sale     2-day-volume    3-day-sale   3-day-volume    
 0    4                10            7            100
```

what I wanted it to be:

```
        2-day    3-day
sale    4        7
volume  10       100
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.rsplit('-', n=1, expand=True)
df.squeeze().unstack().T

        2-day  3-day
sale        4      7
volume     10    100

​
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes. I used exactly the same solution. Much appreciated:)

Answer (score 0):

The following piece of code will get you your desired output. But, I recommend that you read the [pandas data structures documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html) to get a better understanding of what's going on.

```
df_index = ['sale', 'volume']
data = {'2-day': pd.Series([4, 10], index=df_index), 
        '3-day': pd.Series([7, 100], index=df_index)}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Output for `df`:

```
        2-day  3-day
sale        4      7
volume     10    100
```

I hope this answers your question. Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you Onel! Sorry for my late reply...yes, your solution works. And your recommendation of understanding data structures really helped:)